# How to detect if child elements have changed positions?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am creating a generic element that will notify the server when any child elements have changed positions. It is a sortable element where the child elements are items and you can drag them above or below other elements. When the user drops the element it will trigger an event. When the event is triggered it will report back to the server the item positions. My problem is I cannot figure out how to trigger an event when child element positions have changed.

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: For this issue I have not tried anything yet. I did a little research and stumbled upon https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-elements/issues/15. I see it is a proof of concept and not ready for production. Is there an alternative or work around to implement this feature?